# Xcode 6 settings for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, info.plist

Does anybody know why Xcode adds `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key with value `armv7` into **Info.plist** file in new projects? Project is for iOS 8+. In documentation it says:

> Include this key if your app is compiled only for the armv7 instruction set.

So I don't get it. Why does Xcode automatically add this value into Info.plist? Is it a bug?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. This might be added because the latest Xcode don't have support fro armv7. Previously many apps supported both armv6(iphone 3g) and armv7. No to make sure that the AppStore does not offer these apps to device that have an armv6 they added the device requirement.

Comment: I don't think so, because this means that project is compiled **only** for `armv7` and not for e.g. arm64. Moreover this parameter causes the [problem](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/) with application updates.

Comment: Well since the arm64 has support fro the armv7 it does not cause any issues.

Comment: That's true but why don't build application for all supported architectures and restrict building only for armv7. That makes no sense...

Comment: It's needed to make your app unavailable on older device that are not able to run armv7 binaries. Like the iPhone, iPhone 3G.

Comment: And is application builded for arm64 too? Or only for armv7? Because this sentence is in documentation: "app is compiled **only** for the armv7 instruction set."